# Jquery - check the value of inputs texts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input texts like this :

```
<input type="text" value="5" maxlength="12" id="qty" class="input-text qty" name="qty2050" tabindex="1">

and 

<input type="text" value="0" maxlength="12" id="qty" class="input-text qty" name="qty2042" tabindex="1">
```

And I want to check with jquery the values of each input, to execute a function if there is a quantity different from 0 in one input.

**EDIT**
How can I do that on page before unlod?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what do you want to trigger it to be checked? page load/click/change

Comment: I want to check it onbeforeunload, Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? jQuery has good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Are you sure you want it on page unload? Normally you'd wait for a key press or other user event, validate the data and then submit/redirect to a different page.

Comment: I want finally to show an alert, but only if there is a value different of 0 in one of my text fields, If all fields have 0 as a value, I have nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way-

```
$(window).unload(function() {
     $('.input-text qty').each(function (){
         var val = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
         // you can use math.floor if your input value is float-
         //var val = Math.floor($(this).val());
         if(val !== 0)
         alert(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use strict comparison, you have to convert the value to a number first. `.val()` always returns a string.

Comment: In if you can write just this `if (this.value) {` without jquery

Comment: @Vivek : Thanks a lot, I have modify your code, it works nice now, but I want to add an exception in my submit button (if a quantity is > 0).

Here is my code :

`window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 var showAlert = false;
 jQuery('.input-text.qty').each(function (){

  //console.log("fonction 1");
  var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10);
     if(val > 0) { showAlert = true; } 
     //alert(val);
 });
 
 console.log("fonction 2");
 console.log(showAlert);
 
    if (showAlert == true) {
     console.log("fonction 3");
        return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    } 
}`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have two same IDs on a page.
Quite simple should be:

```
$('input.input-text.qty').each(function(){
  if ($(this).val() !== '0') {
    alert('Gotcha!');
    return false; //quit loop since we're ok with 1 occurance
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.input-text').change( function() { 
    if($(this.val() != "0")){ // 
      action here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use change(): http://api.jquery.com/change/

> Example: To add a validity test to all text input elements:

```
$("input[type='text']").change( function() {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkInput = function() {
    if(this.value !== '0') {
        // do something
    }
}

$(window).bind('unload', checkInput);
$('input[type=text]').change(checkInput);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this on the unload event then something like this will work (its untested), otherwise bind to whatever event you want:

```
$(window).unload( function() {
    $('.input-text qty').each(function (){
        if( $(this).val() !== '0' ) {       
            alert("there is a 0");
            return false;//breaks out of the each loop, if this line present will only get one alert even if both fields contain 0
        }
    });
    });
```